# Function address not in the range of memory-mapped files for the lisp image process

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

After defining and disassembling the function `fn`, I can see that the function (or *code component*) resides at memory address 0x53675216. But I don't see said memory address to be in the range of memory-mapped files attributed to the lisp image process (I'm using SBCL).

Am I missing something about how the internals of a process work?

[image]

---

FWIW My goal was to dump the entire memory of the process and inspect some of the memory. But if I can't even get at a function that I defined, what's the point?

Comment: The number printed after "Origin" is a virtual address, looking at the source code, if you `slime-inspect` the function object `#'FN` you might want to look at debug informations (with debug set to 3), e.g. the CODE component has different values in FUN-MAP that might be absolute offsets; alternatively you can look at SB-DISASSEM:DISASSEMBLE-SEGMENTS to see how the memory is really accessed to print the disassembled code

Comment: Here's what I got from your suggestion: (defining `fn` as `defun fn ())`) `(disassemble 'fn)` gives me: "Origin: #x53609A76". `(sb-disassem::disassemble-segments (sb-disassem::get-code-segments (sb-disassem::fun-code-header #'cons)) *standard-output* (sb-disassem::make-dstate))` also gives me: "Origin #x53609A76".

And after inspecting the function using `slime-inspect` I'm being given no new information that `disassemble` doesn't already provide ("Origin: #x53609A76").

Also, I'm not sure what FUN-MAP means.

Comment: You need to recompile with DEBUG set to 3 (here it was 0), so that some debugging informations are kept in memory. When I the Slime inspector with a function compiled with debugging informations, it shows different slots, like NAME, ARGLIST, TYPE, but also CODE. Inspecting the associated value show CODE-SIZE and DEBUG-INFO. This is where I'd start investigating. If later you need to do this programmatically, you'll have to see how Swank/your_lisp accesses those informations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please post the actual text rather than a picture of the text.

`/proc/<pid>/map_files` is not the right thing to look at: instead look at `/proc/<pid>/maps` which shows you all the memory maps.

In my case if I define & compile `foo` on SBCL on x64 / Linux as:

```
(defun foo ())
```

Then `(disassemble 'foo)` looks like:

```
; disassembly for foo
; Size: 21 bytes. Origin: #x53624A7C                          ; foo
[...]
```

And I can use my `hexdump-thing` function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70019565/17026934) to check this:

```
> (hexdump-thing #'foo)
> (hexdump-thing #'foo)
lowtags:    1011
function:   0000000053624A6B : 0000000053624A60
```

So the actual address of the object is `#x0000000053624A60`, which is compatible with what `disassemble` is saying.

So then if I look at `/proc/<pid>/maps` I see, among all the other lines, two lines like:

```
52a00000-533f8000 rwxp 016a8000 fd:00 2758077                            /local/environments/sbcl/lib/sbcl/sbcl.core
533f8000-5ac00000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
```

The fields in this file are address, permissions, offset, device, inode, file.  You can see that the range that includes the function's address is not mapped to any file (note that `p` means 'copy on write' so the range mapped to the core file will never be written back to the core file).

The function's definition lives somewhere in this anonymous range of memory.

---

As a note: if you want to investigate the memory of the implementation, *do it from within the implementation*, which will be hugely easier than trying to investigate it from outside.  SBCL has lots of support for this sort of thing, although you have to find some of them by grovelling around in the source.  After all this sort of thing is exactly what a garbage collector has to do.